# A word the encompasses errors, issues and inaccuracies

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing a document on software testing and am looking for a word that means errors, misunderstandings and inaccuracies. For example when testing you are looking for an error e.g. error in formula, or misunderstandings in the data you are using or that the data is inaccurate. All of these will negatively affect the end results.

The sentence reads
" We will be looking at three types of ______ covering ...."

Is there such a word or phrase, would it be 'issues'?

Comment: 'Issue' usually has the 'problem' sense. 'Problem' and less formally 'snag' always have that sense.

Comment: Of the alternatives suggested in the  “answered previously” link, I recommend *flaw* as appropriate to the circumstances you describe.